# search ruby on rails only for the current_users records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an advanced search page with a seperate search controller for my contracts.

My search is working fine but is searching ALL records, i only want it to search records associated with the current user.

I am using Devise.

Below is my search.rb

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

     def search_contracts
    contracts = Contract.all

    contracts = contracts.where(user_id: current_user)
    contracts = contracts.joins(:tenant).where(["tenants.first_name LIKE ? OR tenants.last_name LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%"]) if keywords.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["balance >= ?", min_balance]) if min_balance.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["balance <= ?", max_balance]) if max_balance.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["unpaid_rent LIKE ?", unpaid_rent]) if unpaid_rent.present?

    return contracts
  end

end
```

Here is my search_controller.rb

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

def new
  @search = Search.new
end

def create
  @search = Search.create!(search_params)
  redirect_to @search
end

def show
  @search = Search.find(params[:id])
end


private

def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:keywords, :min_balance, :max_balance, :unpaid_rent)
end

end
```

show page for search results

```
.wrapper_with_padding
  #houses.clearfix
    - unless @search.user_search_contracts.blank?
      - @search.user_search_contracts.each do |contract|
        %a{ href: (url_for [contract])}
          .house
            %p.end_of_contract= contract.end_of_contract
            %p.balance= number_to_currency(contract.balance, :unit => "£", negative_format: "(%u%n)")
            -if contract.tenant.present?
              %p.tenant_id= contract.tenant.full_name
            -else
              %p No Tenant Assigned
            -if contract.house.present?
              %p.house_id= contract.house.full_house_name
            -else
              %p No Property Assigned

    - else
      %h2 Add a Contract
      %p It appears you have not added any contracts

    %button= link_to "New Contract", new_contract_path
    = link_to "Advanced Search", new_search_path
```

Comment: add initialize method to the Search model and send it a current_user object. Also, you are using `Search.create!(search_params)` as a resource in the DB, do you need to save those searches?

Comment: Hi, @ZlatkoAlomerovic thanks for the advice. I am new to rails so not sure what an initialize method is, please could you show a snippet? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, I wouldn't implement this Search functionality in this way, but ...

Try modifying what @DR7 posted, only create an instance method, not a class method.

```rb
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  def user_search_contracts(user)
    contracts = Contract.where(user_id: user.id)

    contracts = contracts.joins(:tenant).where(["tenants.first_name LIKE ? OR tenants.last_name LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%"]) if keywords.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["balance >= ?", min_balance]) if min_balance.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["balance <= ?", max_balance]) if max_balance.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["unpaid_rent LIKE ?", unpaid_rent]) if unpaid_rent.present?

    return contracts
  end
end
```

And inside your view ->

```rb
.wrapper_with_padding
  #houses.clearfix
    - unless @search.user_search_contracts(current_user).blank?
      - @search.user_search_contracts(current_user).each do |contract|
        %a{ href: (url_for [contract])}
          .house
            %p.end_of_contract= contract.end_of_contract
            %p.balance= number_to_currency(contract.balance, :unit => "£", negative_format: "(%u%n)")
            -if contract.tenant.present?
              %p.tenant_id= contract.tenant.full_name
            -else
              %p No Tenant Assigned
            -if contract.house.present?
              %p.house_id= contract.house.full_house_name
            -else
              %p No Property Assigned

    - else
      %h2 Add a Contract
      %p It appears you have not added any contracts

    %button= link_to "New Contract", new_contract_path
    = link_to "Advanced Search", new_search_path
```

[Class methods vs. Instance methods](https://dev.to/adamlombard/ruby-class-methods-vs-instance-methods-4aje)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a class method to your Search model.

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.user_search_contracts(user)
    user ||= User.new
    contracts = Contract.where(user_id: user.id)

    contracts = contracts.joins(:tenant).where(["tenants.first_name LIKE ? OR tenants.last_name LIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%"]) if keywords.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["balance >= ?", min_balance]) if min_balance.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["balance <= ?", max_balance]) if max_balance.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["unpaid_rent LIKE ?", unpaid_rent]) if unpaid_rent.present?

    return contracts
  end
end
```

Comment: He'll also need to pass the args/keyword args in. It might also be helpful to show example usage on his `create` method

Comment: Hi @DR7 i tried this solution but now i get an error on my search show page for unknown method on form, i will add my show page to question

Comment: @Kush the method is expecting to get an user as argument.Try to add `@search.user_search_contracts(current_user).each`

Comment: @DR7 Still does not work and gets error  `undefined method `user_search_contracts' for #<Search:0xfb085c0>`

Comment: @DR7 this is not working for him, because he is using it inside a view as an instance method, not a class method.